# SharePoint blog posts have empty category when accessing via WCF

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a c# MVC app that is accessing SharePoint blog data via the /_vti_bin/ListData.svc service reference. I am able to successfully get all the PostsItems as well as all the CategoriesItems. However, there appears to be no relationship between them. If I fetch all the posts and loop through them, all of them show zero items in the Category property.

My assumption is that there is a many-to-many table that SharePoint is using that is not available via WCF. I'm wondering if there's a way to access this information. Here is my code.

```
public List<BlogData.PostsItem> GetPostsByCategory(string category)
    {
        List<BlogData.PostsItem> items = new List<BlogData.PostsItem>();
        BlogData.CategoriesItem categoryItem = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Title == category).FirstOrDefault();

        if (categoryItem != null)
        {
            var posts = db.Posts.ToList().OrderByDescending(p => p.Created);
            foreach (var postsitem in posts)
            {
                Debug.Write(postsitem.Category.Count());
                if (postsitem.Category.Contains(categoryItem))
                {
                    items.Add(postsitem);
                }
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Resolved:

Added

```
db.LoadProperty(postsitem, "Category");
```

before

```
if (postsitem.Category.Contains(categoryItem))
```

and it worked like a charm. Thanks, Jason.

EDIT 2:

Apparently, upon further reading, this is not the most efficient method, considering I want to check all the posts for a category. Instead of LoadProperty, I'm using Expand.

```
var posts = db.Posts.Expand("Category").OrderByDescending(p => p.Created);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories are most likely considered a "deferred" item in from the SharePoint ListData service. You will need to load the deferred data when calling the service...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Quick, easy, perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the modified line from my code:


`var posts = db.Posts.Expand("Category").OrderByDescending(p => p.Created);`


Thanks, @Jason.